# People results not returning anything

Tags: user-profile-service, people-search

I've setup UPS and have 7 users from AD. Search has performed a successful crawl and I can search via `Everything` and find user's my-site pages. When I perform a search by `People` it returns no results.

I've given permissions in the UPS application to `Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers` for the access account used for the search application.

The Managed Metadata Service is running.

My Site Search scope for finding people has been set to `People`

I'm not sure why people search is not returning any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check Search Content Sources and make sure people is included
2. Check the Scope and make sure people search is included `sps3://...`

Comment: I had our mysites added with `http://...`. Adding the `sps3://..` and rerunning the crawl brought successfull results. Our production server doesn't have that address scoped though. Could you explain why that is necessary?

Comment: Not sure why this happened, but having the `sps3://...` gave results, but they were in double. So I removed it, leaving the `http://...` and ran the crawl and now it is working fine with no double results. So no I am back to the original setting I had which previously was not returning any results, but is working now.

Comment: Might be some cache issue. Normally we used to restart the search service to resolve issues.